# vmware - ACE, Workstation - how to manage remoe clients?

Tags: remote, vmware-workstation

Exploring Vmware products/services and have a few questions.

As I understand VM, you can use VMWare Workstation to create a VM of a target machine/box/OS. Let's call this VM, "foo".

If I have 100 client PCs in my dept, and I want to install the VM (foo) on each client, and also manage the remote VM instances of (foo). How can I accompish this? Let's assume that the client machines are running Windows7, and have the vmplayer app installed on the box.

I'm looking to do the following kinds of actions regarding the remote client machines:
 -Update the foo VM/image with new updated copies
 -Make sure that every VM "foo" has the same user, but a unique passwd
 -Monitor the traffic/status of each client VM "foo" oin each client 
 -Start/Stop each client VN "foo" from the master console
 -Etc...

Can this be accomplished? How would I do it, what services/products would I need?

I've tried toalking to a few of the pre-sales guys in VMWare, and got nowhere, other than telling me to email my questions!! Looking at google shed more insight, but I still have questions.

So, if you have detailed VMWare understanding, pointers to consultants, or resellers who can help, all pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

-tom

Answer (score 2):

Although I love VM Workstation, it sounds to me that your situation would be much better suited for VMView (formerly VDI). [Link to VMView product at VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/view/)

VMView is really a great concept. It delivers the desktop in a Platform as a Service configuration. Daryl Hunter has a [great blog post](http://www.darylhunter.me/blog/2009/04/vmware-view-part-1-purpose-and-installation.html) on how he implemented VMView for his company.

VMView 4.5 was really a leap forward and in my opinion the best in its class as a thin client.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Check out [vmware ace management server](http://www.vmware.com/products/ace/). It allows the VMs to be installed on the local client machines, but gives you the ability to deploy, manage, and police the VMs.

Cheers,

Jake